# Can Bouncy Castle C# work with .NET Cryptography

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am using Bouncy Castle C# to develop an application. Currently, I can retrieve the certificate list through the X509Store class and get the private key via the RSACryptoServiceProvider class by .NET API.

I would like to export the RSACryptoServiceProvider private key and transform into BC object such as ICipherParameter for encryption/decryption. However, the export action are not allowed since the certificates marked as non-exportable.

1. Is that any alternative solution to retrieve the certificate list and using private key with non-exportable attribute through Bouncy Castle API?

Comment: It wouldn't be very useful if you could simply ignore the non-exportable setting. Don't mark the private keys as non-exportable if you want to export them.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think the question is "can BouncyCastle work off of a CAPI PCERT_CONTEXT? Or, at the very least, a CAPI or CNG named key?"  (Not that I know the answer)

Comment: @bartonjs I have updated the question

Answer (score 4):

No. Bouncy Castle is a software only implementation, especially when it comes to C#. It doesn't contain any plugin structures to perform operations on hardware, at least when it comes to the core cryptographic functionality.

Then again it *is* open source, so it should be possible to change the code. The only problem after that is with keeping your altered code up-to-date.

Comment: 95% sure of this answer, by the way. If somebody posts a 100% sure answer I'll gladly upvote it. Or, for 100% certainty, try the Bouncy mailing lists.

Comment: Can bouncy Castle support to use the private key which retrieved from .NET protected class such as RSACryptoServiceProvider/RSAParameters?

Comment: No, for software encryption to work the key needs to be in accessible memory.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Sadly BouncyCastle C# mailing list is mostly dead. I can confirm your answer is correct. See my older answer to similar question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/29562921/3325704